# Can the requests and responses made in JMeter be seen in Charles Proxy?

Tags: jmeter, charles-proxy

I have a CometD plugin for JMeter and it doesn't show all the details of the exchanged messages (e.g. headers).

I'm troubleshooting an error and I have already managed to configure Charles Proxy to intercept and show all the calls made in Firefox by the application.

Would it be possible to configure Charles to intercept and show all the details of the messages sent/received in JMeter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run JMeter with proxy configuration as per this [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

Example:

> jmeter -H "Host where Charles proxy is running" -P "Charles proxy port"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a proxy consider adding a Listener like "**View Results Tree**." This will capture every request and response. You can view them after the test is completed/stopped.

Comment: I tried and the listener didn't show any headers for the CometD calls.